# SQL 2012 bug for the ACOS function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I run into this bug in SQL Server 2012 ACOS function:

```
declare @lat1 decimal(12,10), @lon1 decimal(12,10), @lat2 decimal(12,10), @lon2 decimal(12,10)
declare @dist float

select @lat1=51.1790825000, @lon1= 4.1590020000, @lat2= 51.1790825000, @lon2= 4.1590020000  
set @dist = SIN(RADIANS(@lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(@lat2)) + COS(RADIANS(@lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(@lat2)) * COS(RADIANS(@lon1 - @lon2))

print @dist
print ACOS(1)
print ACOS(@dist)
```

The last print function gives an "An invalid floating point operation occurred." This works fine in SQL Server 2008

Vlad

Comment: This isn't a question. If you found a bug, post it on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer)

Comment: Same server with 2 different instances or 2 different machines? I get the error on both SQL Server 2012 RC0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my local PC. And on a networked SQL Server 2008 R2. So this comes down to hardware (zhe CPU) probably

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to calculate the distance between two points on the Earth.  Make your life easier and use the built-in geography type.

```
DECLARE @lat1 DECIMAL(12, 10) ,
    @lon1 DECIMAL(12, 10) ,
    @lat2 DECIMAL(12, 10) ,
    @lon2 DECIMAL(12, 10)
DECLARE @dist FLOAT

SELECT  @lat1 = 51.1790825000 ,
        @lon1 = 4.1590020000 ,
        @lat2 = 51.1790825000 ,
        @lon2 = 4.1590020000

DECLARE @p1 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@lat1, @lon1, 4326) ,
    @p2 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@lat2, @lon2, 4326)

SELECT  @dist = @p1.STDistance(@p2)
```

Comment: super cool ! cheers no need for sin cos tan handling urself ! but what is this '4326' ?

Comment: ok got it.  STSrid is an integer representing the spatial reference identifier (SRID) of the instance.

Comment: While convienent, this method is significantly slower than doing the math yourself.  In my own testing I found that doing the math on half a million rows took about 12 seconds compared to using the geography object which was 3 times slower taking 36.  Your hardware is different so test yourself, but be aware that if performance is a consideration you ought to consider avoiding this method.

Comment: @mattmc3: Perhaps. Of course, I'd wager that a lot of that time was spent actually creating the geography instances on the fly. In practice, that's something that you can do once for the points that you're storing in your database and then run the geography methods from there. YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
print ACOS(CASE WHEN @dist > 1 THEN 1 ELSE @dist END)
```

`@dist` is a `float` datatype and is actually slightly more than `1` due to rounding issues as can be seen from below.

```
SELECT CAST(@dist AS BINARY(8)) AS [@dist], 
       CAST(CAST(1 AS FLOAT) AS BINARY(8)) AS [1]
```

Returns

```
@dist              1
------------------ ------------------
0x010000000000F03F 0x000000000000F03F
```

Plugging `010000000000F03F` into [the IEEE converter here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) shows that this is approximately `1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263` which can be verified from the below (returns `Y`)

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN @dist between 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847 AND 
                             1.0000000000000002220446049250313080848 
     THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

Answer (score 1):

The float value argument for acos() function has to be between -1 to 1 range.. Hence

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Calculate_Distance]  
(  
@Lat1 float, @Long1 float, @Lat2 float, @Long2 float  
)  
RETURNS float  
AS  
BEGIN  

    DECLARE @acosValue float     
    DECLARE @R float  
    SET @R = 3958.7558657440545 -- mi       
    DECLARE @Distance float  
    Set @acosValue= cos( radians(@Lat1) ) * cos( radians( @Lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( @Long2 ) - radians(@Long1) ) + sin( radians(@Lat1) ) * sin( radians( @Lat2 ) ) ;
    IF @acosValue>1.0 
    Begin
    Set @acosValue=1.0;
     End
    IF @acosValue<-1.0 
    Begin
    Set @acosValue=-1.0;
     End

    SET @Distance = acos(@acosValue)
     * @R;  

    RETURN @Distance  

END 
GO
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have stated, you have a floating point issue, which will present itself differently based on different CPU architectures.  However, there's a simple one-liner that fixes your issue:

`declare @dist float` needs changed to `declare @dist decimal(12, 10)`.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Casting to decimal(16,15) shaved the precision down and suddenly SQL had no issue distinguishing between ACOS(1) and the invalid ACOS(1.0000000000000001)!