# SQL Server trig functions throwing Invalid Floating Point Operation Occured

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, trigonometry

I'm calling this function with legitimate Lat/Long values to try to calculate the distance between two points. It works perfectly well for 99.99% of all my points, but on this particular point, it's crashing:

```
SELECT ACOS(SIN(-34.8821289 * PI() / 180) 
          * SIN(-34.882129 * PI() / 180) 
          + (COS(-34.8821289 * PI() / 180) 
           * COS(-34.882129 * PI() / 180) 
           * COS((150.7406616 - 150.740662) * PI() / 180))) / (PI() / 180) * 111.325
```

How can I toughen up the function to check for and handle this?

I'd really like to keep using the trig functions and not the native SQL Server geography type for performance reasons.

Comment: This may explain the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188781/sql-2012-bug-for-the-acos-function

Answer (score 0):

Damn, looks like having the mix of some 7 digit decimal place values with the other 6 digit decimal place values, was causing the COS function to be rounded to equal 1, which was then blowing up the overall ACOS function because the 1 is out of range?

By reducing all my input values to 6 digits seems to have fully fixed the issue.

Comment: 1 is not out of range for `ACOS`. If you saw 1 display, it may be because the actual value in the computer was slightly more than 1 but it was displayed without enough digits to show the exact value.